How to build single query in Django with related models and count
I did not use the Django for a years and tried to modify some old codebase today.
I have models:
class MetaTemplate(CreatedModifiedBase):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=200)
class Project(CreatedModifiedBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(
        User,
        through=ProjectMembership,
        related_name="annotation_projects_as_member",
        blank=True,
    )
    metatemplate = models.ForeignKey(
        MetaTemplate, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="project", null=True
    )
class Dataset(CreatedModifiedBase):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, related_name="datasets", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
class Task(CreatedModifiedBase):
    dataset = models.ForeignKey(
        Dataset, related_name="tasks", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True
    )

class Completion(CreatedModifiedBase):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, related_name="completions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    annotator = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name="annotation_completions",
        null=True,
    )

I have a method which returns number of incomplete Tasks.
    def get_incomplete_tasks(self, user, project_id, target_completion_count) -> int:
        return (
            Task.objects.annotate(counts=Count("completions"))
            .filter(
                counts__lt=target_completion_count,
                dataset__project=project_id,
            )
            .exclude(completions__annotator=user)
            .prefetch_related(
                "completions", "completions__annotator", "dataset__project"
            )
            .count()
        )

Now I want to rework this method and return the number of incomplete Tasks for each of the projects in single query without project_id and target_completion_count passed by user. So basically the same logic but per in one query per Project.
I wrote this code:

            t = Task.objects.filter(
                dataset__project=OuterRef('id')
            )
            completion_count_subquery = t.exclude(completions__annotator=user).prefetch_related(
                "completions", "completions__annotator").order_by().annotate(
                    counts=Func(F('id'), function='Count')).values('counts')
            objects = Project.objects.all().annotate(task_count=Subquery(completion_count_subquery)).prefetch_related("members", "metatemplate")

But I am not able to include counts__lt=target_completion_count part in the proper way.
Also tried this query
            t = Task.objects.all().annotate(counts=Count("completions")).filter(dataset__project = OuterRef('id'), counts__lt=OuterRef("target_completion_count")).order_by().values("completions")
            completion_count_subquery = t.exclude(completions__annotator=user)
            objects = Project.objects.all().annotate(task_count=Subquery(completion_count_subquery)).prefetch_related("members", "metatemplate")

But it ends wit error django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

The revised version of your code to avoid getting the programmingError you are having due to more than one row returned.
Thus, to achieve the goal of returning the number of incomplete tasks for each project in a single query, we’ll need to adjust your approach to use Django’s ORM capabilities effectively. Here’s a revised version of your code that I believe should work.
Here is how:
Feel free to delete the comments that I wrote to explain to you what I did.

t = Project.objects.annotate(
    incomplete_tasks_count=Subquery(
        Task.objects.filter(
            dataset__project=OuterRef('pk'),
            completions__annotator=user
        ).annotate(
            completions_count=Count('completions')
        ).filter(
            completions_count__lt=OuterRef('target_completion_count')
        ).values('completions_count')[:1],
        output_field=models.IntegerField()
    )
).prefetch_related("members", "metatemplate")




NB: Please note that target_completion_count should be a field in the Project model for this to work. If it’s not, you’ll need to adjust the query accordingly to provide the target completion count for each project imo. Goodluck
PS: I modified the code a bit to tackle the FieldError you are getting, however, ensure that target_completion_count is in the field of the Project model because I couldn't see it when I took a closer look at your models. If it is not there, do add it up pls. Without the target_completion_count, the OuterRef can't look for it to compare with completions_count.

Yes, target_completion_count is a field in the Project model. Using your query I am getting django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unsupported lookup 'count' for ManyToOneRel or join on the field not permitted. Error in completions__count__lt=OuterRef('target_completion_count') in Task.objects.filter part

that's weird. I hope you have migrated some necessary changes in your dB? I want to see what the createmodifiedbase class inherited from, add it up to your initial model.py code?

I had modified the code a bit. Kindly check, and get back, pls read the whole statement I wrote above.
